# BIOS does not see my SSD as a boot drive

Tags: boot, server, system-installation, ssd, bios

I have a computer running Ubuntu server. I recently upgraded this computer with a new motherboard, CPU, memory and power supply. I am using the same SSD with Ubuntu server installed. My BIOS recognizes this SSD as a drive, however it does not see it as a boot device. Is there anything I can do to fix this besides reinstalling my OS?

Note: My old CPU was AMD and the new one is Intel.

- Motherboard: ASRock Phantom Gaming 4 HS70
- CPU: Intel Core i5 11400
- SSD: Micron 1100 m.2 SATA 256GB
- OS: Ubuntu server (unknown version)

Comment: This would probably depend on the motherboard, not the contents of the storage devices. Either way, there’s no way to answer this without knowing the brand and model of motherboard, as no two are alike 

Comment: You've provided no specifics; what OS, product, release etc. did the old motherboard boot the same way as the new one (ie. BIOS on new one is using the same config setup options as prior one? otherwise it may not boot an installed OS that isn't setup for that config) etc...

Comment: You may have originally installed Ubuntu Server with your old motherboard in a different mode (CSM vs. UEFI) than  your new motherboard is currently configured for.

Comment: “Unknown version” of Ubuntu Server? If you don’t know the version, don’t expect it to start up and recognize an 11th generation Core processor and all the chipsets required to make the thing work. If you need to save data off the drive, grab a Live USB of Ubuntu Desktop 21.10, mount the SSD, and copy to a location. Then reinstall  a modern release of Ubuntu Server (or Desktop) 

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my old motherboard was using CSM and my new motherboard uses UEFI. I installed Ubuntu server again, and then deleted all of the folders besides /boot and copied all my old folders back in. This is probably not recommended as there were a lot of errors, but it worked well enough for me to get the data out of my docker containers.